# Is it possible to make this a lambda function?

Tags: python

```
def min_max(arr):
    max_vals = list(itertools.accumulate(map(len, arr)))
    min_vals = [0] + max_vals[:-1]
    return min_vals, max_vals
```

Is it possible to convert this to a lambda function, if so what would it look like?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 3.8 or newer you can do it with assignment expressions

```
min_max = lambda arr: ((max_vals := list(itertools.accumulate(map(len, arr)))), [0] + max_vals[:-1])
print(min_max([...])[::-1])
```

the `[::-1]` is to reverse the order of `min_vals` and `max_vals`, it's not necessary if you don't mind the order.